# Electron.js Function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, electron

I'm generating dynamic table using JavaScript with a "getCutomerEmail" button on last column of each row. Now i want to extract email value when click on "getCutomerEmail" button on the same row.

I declared two functions on Preload.js to extract email and send it to the main.js for further processing:

```
function  getEmail (el)  {
  const tr = el.closest("tr");
  const tds = tr.getElementsByClassName('email');
  const emailAddress = tds[0].innerHTML;
  console.log(emailAddress);
  ipcRenderer.send("ClickRunCH", emailAddress);

}
```

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
function renderCustomers(tasks) {
customerList.innerHTML += `
    <tr >
        <th >Name</th>
        <th >Email</th>
        <th >Contacts</th>
        <th >Address</th>
        <th >Country</th>
        <th >Action</th>
    </tr>`;    
tasks.forEach((t) => {
  customerList.innerHTML += `
    <tr class=" animated bounceInUp">
        <td >${t.Name}</td>
        <td >${t.Email}</td>
        <td >${t.Contacts}</td>
        <td >${t.Address}</td>
        <td >${t.Country}</td>
        <td ><button class="email" onclick="getEmail(this)">
            Get Customer Email
        </button></td>
    </tr>`;
});

})
```

**But i'm getting this error message:**

```
ReferenceError: getEmail is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Any help is really appreciated, thnx for reading

Answer (score 0):

Functions cannot be accessed from other files unless they are exported from the file where they are defined & imported in the file where they are used.

You need to use export keyword in preload.js...

```
export function  getEmail (el)  {
  const tr = el.closest("tr");
  const tds = tr.getElementsByClassName('email');
  const emailAddress = tds[0].innerHTML;
  console.log(emailAddress);
  ipcRenderer.send("ClickRunCH", emailAddress);

}
```

In main.js (where function is used) you need to import it

```
import {getEmail} from 'preload.js'
```

But you need to provide the path if preload.js & main.js are not in the same directory.

```
import {getEmail} from 'otherPath/preload.js'
```

that will depend entirely on where the files are in relation to each other.

Comment: But i need to execute this function on Preload.js not on Main.js. I'll send results to Main.js.

Comment: all i need is to execute getEmail() function when click on button with class="email"

Comment: I think dynamic table is generated before function is declarer, But how could ii declare function before table generation?!